# Linking data between Vue instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I trimmed out a lot of the code, but basically I want `vmTimer.step` to mirror `vmPurchase.step`.  According to the "Data Proxying" section of http://vuejs.org/api/#Data_Proxying, I should be doing it correct, right?  When  `vmPurchase.step` gets changed to `1`, it's still `0` under `vmTimer.step`

```
var vmPurchase = new Vue({
    data: {
        step: 0
    }
});

var vmTimer = new Vue({
    data: {
        step: vmPurchase.$data.step // sync the steps
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `data` section does not perform a binding – it performs an initialization. You need to incorporate a `watch` something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidkhess/xkyeymvp/

```
var vmPurchase = new Vue({
    data: {
        step: 0
    }
});

var vmTimer = new Vue({
    el: "#main",
    data: {
        vmPurchase: vmPurchase,
        step: vmPurchase.step
    },
    methods: {
        increment: function () {
            vmPurchase.step += 1;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        "vmPurchase.step": function (newValue, oldValue) {
            this.step = vmPurchase.step;
        }
    }
});
```

with

```
<div id="main">
    {{ step }}
    <button type="button" v-on="click: increment">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Note, you are creating two different Vue hierarchies by the two different `new` statements which is a bit of a style issue. In order to take advantage of "props" and "events" you would normally make one a component of the other which puts them into a related hierarchy.